# Boas praticas de testes em python

Tags: python, testes

estou a uma semana estudando testes em python, comecei com unittest e algumas duvidas surgiram...Devo usar uma classe de testes para cada método de uma classe, ou utilizo uma classe de teste para cada classe...e ainda, como proceder com funções que não pertencem a uma classes?

Comment: Testes unitários devem possuir um teste para cada unidade de código - bem sugestivo, não? Assim, você que deverá definir isso. Seu método tem um caso de teste? Então um método de teste basta. Seu método possui vários casos de testes? Então apenas um não bastará.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `unittest` exige que os testes estejam em classes mais por conta da forma como ele é implementado - fica prático buscar subclasses de UnitTests, e ter os métodos de setup e teardown para um conjunto de testes - do que para corresponder a qualquer divisão de classes do seu programa.

Então - se você tem funções que não estão em classes, tem que por os testes em uma classe da mesma forma. Tenha em mente que testes na mesma classe podem compartilhar os métodos de setup e teardown.

Na verdade, apesar do unitest estar na biblioteca padrão, hoje em dia a maior parte da comunidade Python usa a biblioteca [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) para testes. Dentre os vários motivos de seu uso se destaca justamente uma menor burocracia para escrever seus testes - se faz sentido agrupa-los em classes, faça-o, mas a maior parte dos projetos agrupa os testes em arquivos .py que tem a ver com o mesmo assunto.

Dentre as outras vantagens do `pytest` estão: é mais fácil para qualquer usuário do seu projeto executar os testes - desenvolvedores Python estão acostumados a chamar  `py.test`. É extremamente versátil para produzir dados que serão usados como "fixtures". Tem plug-ins para coverage e estatísticas e profiling, dentre outras coisas.

Ma spor que então não está na biblioteca padrão? Em anos recentes a comunidade Python opta por não colocar algumas bibliotecas que são usadas quase universalmente dentro da linguagem justamente para não travar seu desenvolvimento. Colocar a pytest ou a requests na stdlib do Python limitaria que versões com novas funcionalidades dessas bibliotecas só fossem liberadas a cada nova versão do Python. Mais ainda - versões para corrigir pequenos bugs também teriam que seguir o ciclo de micro-versões de Python - que pode durar vários meses (e as vezes os fixes são urgentes). Além disso os contribuidores desses projetos, além de seguirem o crivo e processos de cada projeto estariam também restritos pelos processos para inclusão na própria linguagem. Uma boa forma de entender isso é justamente a unittest: ela foi incorporada ao Python há mais de 10 anos, e praticamente parou no tempo, com nenhuma funcionalidade nova.

Comment: Obrigado Bueno...que resposta...vou dar uma pesquisada no pytest..fiquei bem animado.